# Reclassifying Raster to Vectorize in ArcScan

Tags: raster, arcmap, reclassify, vectorization, arcscan

I have a raster file featuring sidewalks for an entire city. I created this raster from polygons with the intention of using ArcScan to extract a centerline from the raster. I know that the raster has to have exactly 2 values within it. However, I'm having a problem with the vectorization where only one of the values is able to be vectorized at a time, but I cannot control it. Is the raster supposed to be in the form of, say, 0 = no data cells and 1 = sidewalks? If so, how can I change the values to match that? I've tried simply reclassifying the raster to be 0 and 1 (see below), but I get this error:

ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).

[image]

Comment: Esri suggest the image format is tif https://community.esri.com/thread/167272 the create a shapefile that can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also considered extracting the centerline from the polygon before rasterizing? There used to be a tool called ETGeowizard, an extension on top of ArcGIS that I have used in the past to extract a river’s centerline.